# Where clause with linq in readOnlyCollection of Object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a readOnlyCollection of ModuleViewModel, I want to retrieve with linq a specific ModuleViewModel containing in my collection.

Here the declaration of my collection :

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<ModuleViewModel> colModuleViewModel { get; set; }

colModuleViewModel = new ReadOnlyCollection<ModuleViewModel>(
                (from mod in currentProg.Tests.Values
                 select new ModuleViewModel(mod))
             .ToList<ModuleViewModel>());
```

My ModuleViewModel Class :

```
 public class ModuleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        readonly ReadOnlyCollection<ModuleViewModel> _children;
        readonly ModuleViewModel _parent;
        readonly Module _module;

        public ReadOnlyCollection<ModuleViewModel> Children
        {
            get { return _children; }
        }

        bool _isExpanded;
        bool _isSelected;

        public ModuleViewModel(Module module)
            : this(module, null)
        {

        }

        private ModuleViewModel(Module module, ModuleViewModel parent)
        {
            _module = module;
            _parent = parent;

            if (module is Task)
            {
                _children = new ReadOnlyCollection<ModuleViewModel>(
                    (from mod in ((Task)module).Tests.Values
                     select new ModuleViewModel(mod, this))
                 .ToList<ModuleViewModel>());
            }
            else
            {
                _children = null;
            }
        }

        public ModuleViewModel Parent
        {
            get { return _parent; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _module.Name; }
        } 

        public string Id
        {
            get { return (_module is Test ? ((Test)_module).Id : ((Task)_module).Id); }
        }
   }
```

I have the Id of the ModuleViewModel :

```
string idMod = ((Module)currentProgram.finalDico[data.ToString()]).Id;
```

I want to retrieve the ModuleViewModel where Id == idMod

> object obj = from c in colModuleViewModel where ?? select c;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The where condition is trivial: `c.Id == idMod`:

   ```
   from c in colModuleViewModel where c.Id == idMod select c
   ```
2. As you want only a single object and not a collection of objects, you have to use `FirstOrDefault()`:

   ```
   (from c in colModuleViewModel where c.Id == idMod select c).FirstOrDefault();
   ```
3. The query syntax is not beneficial in this scenario, you better use the method chains syntax:

   ```
   object obj = colModuleViewModel.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == idMod);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
object obj = (from c in colModuleViewModel where c.Module.Id == Id select c).FirstOrDefault();
```